# Joining name in SQl

Tags: mysql, sql, rdbms

I am new to SQL and i am tasked with joining the first name and last name of actors in MySQL.

```
select first_name ||''|| last_name name
from actor
order by actor_id;
```

I did this but it is not working. All i get is a string of Zeros. something like

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

If someone could help me solve this problem. that will be wonderful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use Concat Function

```
select CONCAT(first_name, last_name) AS name
from actor
order by actor_id;
```

Further details are [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

Answer (score 1):

use concat() function...

```
select concat(first_name, ' ', last_name) as name
from actor 
order by actor_id;
```

try this one.. hope this help

Comment: Your Welcome.. :)